# How to specify Access Control parameters for a video in YouTube V3 API

Tags: youtube-api

In YouTube V2 API while uploading a video one can specify access control parameters like rate, comment, videoRespond, embed etc.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos

However in V3 API, the video resource doesn't seem to have the part for access control.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource

Is there a way in V3 API to do the same.

Comment: Click Star to get updated on request for [AccessControl Attributes][1]


  [1]: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=473

Comment: Google developers have migrated the issues list to GitHub.com. Subscribe to updates about this issue here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/473#thread-subscription-status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now v3 only has [embed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) one. Other ones should be ported soon as well.

Answer (score 0):

embed settings seems doen't work with .Net api.
I also don't find access control on Youtube Api V3.

Regards.